# LUIS Programmatic API : Publish 400 Error

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

After adding an example and training my model in LUIS, I'm trying to use the Publish Operation in LUIS API to publish new model.

here is my request :

```
{
  "BotFramework": {
    "Enabled": true,
    "AppId": "7daab714-6d78-4613-b8e1-f0e67xxxxxxx",
    "SubscriptionKey": "kVXE8HHE2UQ3NygUWxxxxxx",
    "Endpoint": "https://AppNamexxx.azurewebsites.net/api/messages"
  },
  "Slack": {
    "Enabled": true,
    "ClientId": "136134600708.1353509xxxxx",
    "ClientSecret": "853a5c22a9fc09f7fafd85b1cd9xxxxx",
    "RedirectUri": "https://slack.botframework.com"
  }
}
```

I got this response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "Cannot find an application with the specified ID"
  }
}
```

I'm using the AppId from my bot, I don't understand why itcouldn't find it...

[image: My app ID]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the appId in the URL needs to be the id of your Luis application and not the one of the bot. Check the [Publish](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56d95961e597ed0f04b76e58/operations/56f8a55119845511c81de482) operation of the API.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved :
to publish you app you have to use this operation :

**publishConfigurations - get Publish Configurations**

then execute the publish with the response on this app